# OperationalError at / no such column:core_item.brands_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am having a tricky database problem.
I have a set of categories that display on the nav bar, once you click on those categories, there is a filter called brand, and this brand filter is supposed to take you to a page where they have products under that category (e.g. makup) and display those items.

So I tried to have two foreign keys in my items module as below.

**Models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:category", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
        

class Brand(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:brand", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
   



class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,  related_name='category')
    brands = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,  related_name='brands')
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    stock_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description_short = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_long = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

The error that I am getting, is as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 166, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: core_item.brands_id
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after adding the foreign keys or making changes to your models?

Comment: Yes I did. The migrations went down fine but I still get the error.

Comment: if you don't have any important data in database.  you can delete db.sqlite3 file. then makemigrations and migrate.